# Using javascript, how convert to JSON, Java-POJO-like classes?

Tags: javascript, json, pojo, stringify

I want use Java-POJO-like classes in my JS project: only private fields, getters and setters.

```
function Event() {
var homeTeam;
var awayTeam;
var id;
var singleBets = [];
var bet;

...

this.getHomeTeam = function(){
    return homeTeam;
}
this.setHomeTeam = function(data){
    homeTeam = data;
}

this.getAwayTeam = function(){
    return awayTeam;
}
this.setAwayTeam = function(data){
    awayTeam = data;
}

this.getId = function(){
    return id;
}
this.setId = function(data){
    id = data;
}

this.getSingleBets = function(){
    return singleBets;
}
this.setSingleBets = function(data){
    singleBets = data;
}

this.getBet = function(){
    return bet;
}
this.setBet = function(data){
    bet = data;
}

}
```

I would convert my Java-POJO-like class in a JSON string to send it to the server.
I can't use JSON.stringify(myClass) because the fields are private.
So I think to use a recursive method like this...

```
var myJsonParse = function(data){
    var result = "";
    for(var propertyName in data) {
        var method = propertyName;
        if (method.substring(0,3)=="get"){
            ... data[propertyName].call() ...
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

...but before I spend many time to write it I want ask you if exist a better way to convert the Java-POJO-like object in JSON.
Thank you.

**Update #1**

I am ashamed of myself! This is my working (but absolutely temporary) solution:

```
this.toJSON = function() {
    var bettableEventsString =  [];
    for (var i = 0, len = bettableEvents.length; i < len; i++) {
        bettableEventsString[i] = bettableEvents[i].toJSON();
    }
    var result = JSON.stringify({
        userId: userId,
        championshipDayId: championshipDayId,
        championshipDayName: championshipDayName
    });

    result = result.substring(0, result.length-1);
    result += ',\n  "bettableEvents" : [ ' + bettableEventsString + " ] ";
    result += " } "

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Yes it is a good idea, but I don't know how make this method it recursive with internal object (in my example Bet, SingleBet[])!

Comment: i was saying that this whole POJO thing to be implemented with the Module pattern if possible. http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#modulepatternjavascript
i never tried to json-ize though

Comment: Why are you using getters and setters in Javascript???

Comment: @jan I thought to realize a Java-like application and handle it like I handle Java ones. I don't know if it was a good idea!

Answer (score 1):

The only simple way I can think of is to add an export method:

```
this.toJSON = function() {
    return JSON.stringify({
        homeTeam: homeTeam,
        awayTeam: awayTeam,
        id: id,
        // etc...
    });
}
```

Comment: Ok, really thanks! I can renounce about the generality of the method, but how can I fix this solution to work with the fields that are POJO themselves?

Comment: @valerio That's a harder problem to solve, because that would require you to provide a method that builds a (potentially) recursive array structure ... there are some issues with that, because if you don't clone your structures it would allow modifications made from outside.

Comment: I followed your advice with small correction! Thanks. Update#1